# Can't load link postgreSQL to Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I've created a new Django project in my virtual environment and installed psycopg2. I changed my settings.py file to the following:

```
DB_NAME = "neighborhood"
DB_USER = "django"
DB_PASSWORD = "password"
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

But when I run `python manage.py migrate` in my virtual enviorment, I get the following error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.
I'm using python v3.9 and postgreSQL v13. I checked other posts on Stack Overflow but none answered my problem. Thanks.

Comment: How did you install `psycopg2`?  If `psycopg2-binary` then it is not supported on Python 3.9 yet. See this [Issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1160).

Comment: I just used ```pip install psycopg2```. When that didn't work though, I also installed ```pip install psycopg2-binary```. This is now my requirements.txt file: asgiref==3.3.0
Django==3.1.3
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pytz==2020.4
sqlparse==0.4.1

Comment: Define `pip install psycopg2` didn't work? It didn't install or it installed and then didn't work? If `psycopg2` installed I would uninstall  `psycopg2-binary`  and try your connection again. If that fails report the error in your question above.

Comment: When I said it didn't work I meant that I got the same error. I just uninstalled psycopg2-binary and still no luck. Is it worth uninstalling python 3.9 and installing 3.8.6 instead?

Comment: Yeah, I would do that. Seems to be Appveyor/Windows issue as `psycopg2` works in Python 3.9  here on a Linux machine.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `_psycopg2` from `ENGINE`:

```
DB_NAME = "neighborhood"
DB_USER = "django"
DB_PASSWORD = "password"
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: After removing it I still get the error ```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.```